# SSO Sustainsys.Saml2.Owin Request is not Authenticated - access_denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, single-sign-on, sustainsys-saml2

I have to do SSO authentication with saml2 for my existing asp.net web application.

I am using Sustainsys.Saml2.Owin example to do that.

Identity provider is Azure ADFS ( https://sts.windows.net/TENANTID )

I have configured the Startup file. It loads the metadata file and certificate.

And in my Login page, I am challenging if not authenticated.

It is successfully redirecting to the login page but the Request is never getting authenticated after the login. And in the reply URL we are getting **error=access_denied**

[neither Request.IsAuthenticated or owinContext.Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is set to true]

So it keep on challenging for many times and error with bad request.

What I am doing wrong? 
Which module of Owin/Sustainsys is reposnsible to set the IsAuthenticated status?

*a Saml2. **cookie** [Saml2.DAeP63c***UTX0h***_***] is passed along with the request after login into Microsoft [https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANTID/saml2]

**Startup.cs** file

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        try
        {
            appBuilder.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            appBuilder.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            appBuilder.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            appBuilder.UseSaml2Authentication(CreateSaml2Options());
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {

        }
    }


    private Saml2AuthenticationOptions CreateSaml2Options()
    {
        try
        {
            var spOptions = CreateSPOptions();

            var Saml2AuthOptions = new Saml2AuthenticationOptions(false)
            {
                SPOptions = spOptions,
                Notifications = new Saml2Notifications(),
            };

            var idp = new IdentityProvider(new EntityId(authority), spOptions)
            {
                MetadataLocation = metadataLocation,
                Binding = Saml2BindingType.HttpRedirect
            };

            idp.SigningKeys.AddConfiguredKey(
                new X509Certificate2(certificateLocation));

            Saml2AuthOptions.IdentityProviders.Add(idp);

            return Saml2AuthOptions;
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
        }
    }

    private SPOptions CreateSPOptions()
    {
        try
        {
            var engAus = "en-AU";

            var organization = new Organization();

            var spOptions = new SPOptions
            {
                EntityId = new EntityId(ApplicationId),
                ReturnUrl = new Uri(redirectUrl),
                Organization = organization,
            };

            return spOptions;
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
        }
    }
```

**Login.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        IOwinContext owinContext = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext();

        //if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        if (owinContext.Authentication.User != null &&
            owinContext.Authentication.User.Identity != null &&
            owinContext.Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            //Authenticated
            string name = owinContext.Authentication.User.Identity.Name;
        }
        else
        {
            var authenticationTypes = owinContext.Authentication.GetAuthenticationTypes().Select(d => d.AuthenticationType).ToArray();

            owinContext.Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }, authenticationTypes);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

(all code posted here are the same sample from Github)

You need to understand how SAML works, here's a simple saml implementation class that I used before I dive into SustainsysSAML. [AspNetSaml](https://github.com/jitbit/AspNetSaml/blob/master/Saml.cs)

This is the basic flow of SAML Implementation:

1. User access your app, if user is not yet authenticated your app should redirect the user to your saml provider.

   ```
   //specify the SAML provider url here, aka "Endpoint"
   var samlEndpoint = "http://saml-provider-that-we-use.com/login/";

   var request = new AuthRequest(
   "http://www.myapp.com", //put your app's "unique ID" here
   "http://www.myapp.com/SamlConsume" //assertion Consumer Url - the redirect URL where the provider will send authenticated users
   );

   //generate the provider URL
   string url = request.GetRedirectUrl(samlEndpoint);

   //then redirect your user to the above "url" var
   //for example, like this:
   Response.Redirect(url);
   ```
2. From saml provider, user enters credentials and if valid user, saml provider will authenticate and redirect the user to your app.
3. SAML provider will  post the samlresponse to your app (eg. http://www.myapp.com/SamlConsum).

   ```
   //ASP.NET MVC action method... But you can easily modify the code for Web-forms etc.
   public ActionResult SamlConsume()
   {
       //specify the certificate that your SAML provider has given to you
       string samlCertificate = @"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
   BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH123543==
   -----END CERTIFICATE-----";

       Saml.Response samlResponse = new Response(samlCertificate);
       samlResponse.LoadXmlFromBase64(Request.Form["SAMLResponse"]); //SAML providers usually POST the data into this var

       if (samlResponse.IsValid())
       {
           //WOOHOO!!! user is logged in
           //YAY!

           //Some more optional stuff for you
           //lets extract username/firstname etc
           string username, email, firstname, lastname;
           try
           {
               username = samlResponse.GetNameID();
               email = samlResponse.GetEmail();
               firstname = samlResponse.GetFirstName();
               lastname = samlResponse.GetLastName();
           }
           catch(Exception ex)
           {
               //insert error handling code
               //no, really, please do
               return null;
           }

           //user has been authenticated, put your code here, like set a cookie or something...
           //or call FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie() or something
       }
   }
   ```
4. Your app will read the samlresponse and if valid will let the user use your app, your app will now handle the roles of the user depending on your policies.

Some tips:

1. Make sure your app is identifiable by your saml provider.
2. Use Firebug to trace your http requests (or any http tracing tool)
3. Understand the difference between samlresponse and samlrequest
4. Using Firebug you should be able to see the samlresponse.
5. If you have multiple web apps that you want to have SSO using your saml provider. I suggest you create an httprequest/httphandler to handle the samlresponse from your provider. You can then install this dll to your server and just add the handler to each web app's config. No code change require to your web apps :).

I hope this helps.

Comment: the link is on my answer above, and as I said in the first line of my answer. (all code posted here are the same sample from Github)

Comment: my problem is actually, not receiving "SAMLResponse" in Request.Form.

Comment: All I can see is a cookie [Saml2. cookie] in the request. How do I process that?

Comment: you should be able to see it using Firebug when your SAMLProvider post the SAMLResponse to your site.

Comment: Yes. I am using firebug. but no SAMLResponse